# how do i dynamically change image in css with in :before rules?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I trying to change Background image dynamically but I can't access wrapper with before "wrapper:before{} from jQuery $('.wrapper:before)

```
.wrapper:before {
content: "";
position: fixed;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: -1;
display: block;
background: url("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/m1gYsC1uAu6EDc5pVIZ29DgwSrH.jpg");
background-size: cover;
width: inherit;
height: inherit;
-webkit-filter: blur(25px);
-moz-filter: blur(25px);
-o-filter: blur(25px);
-ms-filter: blur(25px);
filter: blur(25px);
}


.wrapper {
display: inherit !important;
height: 100% !important;
width: 100% !important;
padding: unset !important;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 0;
color: #aaa;
overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

the jQuery looks like this

```
var image = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/" + data.backdrop_path;
    $('.wrapper:before').css('background-image', 'url('+image+')');
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The `wrapper.before` will not allow an image reference however you can use jQuery to look for the `wrapper.before` and add a class. The `wrapper.before` will render as `::before` within the .wrapper div so using some jQuery, you can target the div if it contains the string `::before` and add a class.

```
$("div,wrapper:contains('::before')").addClass("monkey");
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/timhjellum/6751wfrc/47/)

Comment: hello tim, thanks for your response but am still unable to dynamically change the background image via jquery